# Getting the wordpress post/page ID on page load and storing it in a varriable

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I retrieve the Post or Page ID and store it in a variable to be used anywhere like within a shortcode processing data?

I have a function that processes a download button and would like to store the Page/Post ID that the download was processed together with timestamp in order that I do some tracking on which page/post the download was made.

Here is the data that is currently being stored and I would like to add the post_ID() data as well...

```
$data_id = $wpdb->get_row("select * from ahm_files where id='$id'",ARRAY_A); 
$wpdb->insert('wp_ahm_download_stats',array('pid'=>$data['id'], 'month_of_download'=>date('Y-M'),'year'=>date('Y'),'month'=>date('m'),'day'=>date('d'), 'timestamp'=>time(), 'ip'=>$ip),array('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'));]
```

Thank you,

Eric

This is part of the code of the processing function..

```
else {    

    $id = (int)$id;
    $data = $wpdb->get_row("select * from ahm_files where id='$id'",ARRAY_A);
}




    if($data['download_count']>=$data['quota']&&$data['quota']>0)        wp_die('Download Limit Excedded!');

    //added for download monitor import feature
    $data['file'] = str_replace(site_url('/'),ABSPATH, $data['file']);

    if(strpos($data['file'],'ttp://')){
        header("location: ".$data['file']);
        die();
    }
    $data['file'] = trim($data['file']);
    if(file_exists($data['file']) && $data['file']!= "")
    $fname = $data['file'];    
    else if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $data['file']) && $data['file']!= "")
    $fname = UPLOAD_DIR . $data['file'];
    else if( $data['file']== "")
        wp_die("No file attached yet.");
    else 
    wp_die('File not found!');



    $wpdb->query("update ahm_files set download_count=download_count+1 where id='$data[id]'");




    $wpdb->insert('wp_ahm_download_stats',array('pid'=>$data['id'], 'month_of_download'=>date('Y-M'),'year'=>date('Y'),'month'=>date('m'),'day'=>date('d'), 'timestamp'=>time(), 'ip'=>$ip),array('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'));



    $filetype = wp_check_filetype($fname);

    $mtype = $filetype['type'];

    $asfname = basename($fname);

    $fsize = filesize($fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although possible, what you're trying to do is kind of complicating your initial problem.

If everything you want is to track the behavior of the user, in this case, from which page the download was done, the task is much easier: **Use Google Analytics [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).**

Basically you add an onclick parameter to the action the user does, and the trigger will send a special event to Google Analytics where you can access the source (your page), the location, etc.

The code would look something like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download Event', 'Download', 'Title of the Downloaded File']);">Download</a>
```

**EDIT -** Since the my answer above doesn't solve the problem, here's how you can get the ID of the post:

So, the main function to get the ID, as the answer below states is get_the_id(), however if you can't get it, there are other ways:

By slug:

```
// Usage:
// get_id_by_slug('any-page-slug');

function get_id_by_slug($page_slug) {
    $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
    if ($page) {
        return $page->ID;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Credits to the guy [here](https://gist.github.com/davidpaulsson/9224518)

**OR:**

Another way to do it:

```
<?php 

$slug = $post->post_name;

$my_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '$slug'"); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you fr your response, I do not just want to tracking since that one I have already taken care of and it is saving the document ID and the date and the timestamp among other details to my tracking table, what I have failed to get right is picking the post ID that the shortcode is embedded in. Once I am able to pull the post_id that the download shortcode is, it will enable me save the post ID as well, since I will need the post ID in the tracking table to join with the post ID in the wp_post table. that is why I need it so much. Regards

Comment: I've updated my answer by introducing a method to get page ID by slug, you just have to get the slug by doing $post->post_name;

Answer (score 0):

The [Wordpress Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) provides the `get_the_ID()` function to get the Id of the current post:

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I had done that but it still returned zero ID. Could it be that I am putting it in the wrong loop?

I will try putting it above the data processing loop and see what it returns... Thanks